# Drop-down change -data showing [object object]

Tags: angular, angular6

am trying to bind JSON data to a drop-down list.OnChnge function I pass the value to the corresponding component, when I debug it showing `[object object]`.

My JSON value

```
dataLists = [
    { 'id': 1, 'host_name': 'Service 1', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user1', 'password': 'abc' },
    { 'id': 2, 'host_name': 'Service 1', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user2', 'password': 'abc' },
    { 'id': 3, 'host_name': 'Service 1', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user3', 'password': 'abc' }
];
```

html code

```
<select #selectedData (change)="selected($event,selectedData.value)">
            <option>Select....</option>
            <option *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists"  [value]="dataList">{{dataList.host_name}}</option>
        </select>
```

component code

```
selected(ev: Event, data: any []) {
        // console.log('data', data);
        for (const ea of data) {
            console.log(ea);

        }
```

How can i get data as json format in component.
like `{ 'id': 1, 'host_name': 'Service 1', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user1', 'password': 'abc' }`

Comment: I hope this one helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vecfk6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `value` property accepts string value(converting object into a string would results `[object object]`). To use the object as value use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#ngValue) property which accepts any type as the value.

```
<option *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists"  [ngValue]="dataList">{{dataList.host_name}}</option>
```

---

Final code would be like:

***Template:***

```
<select #selectedData (change)="selected($event,selectedData.value)">
  <option>Select....</option>
  <option *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists" [ngValue]="dataList">{{dataList.host_name}}</option>
</select>
```

***TS:***

```
selected(ev: Event, data: any) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: i can able to display value in drop-down.on change of this drop down i pass dataList to component .Each data list having json.In component side its showing as [object object]

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your code as below.

**HTML :**

```
<select  (change)="selected()" [(ngModel)]="drp_selectedValue">
        <option>Select....</option>
        <option *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists" (click)="selectedEA(dataList)" 
          [ngValue]="dataList">{{dataList.host_name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

**ts :**

```
 drp_selectedValue :any;


 selected() {
   console.log( this.drp_selectedValue);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

change [value] to [ngValue] it will work.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedDataList" (change)="selected()">
   <option>Select....</option>
   <option *ngFor="let data of dataLists" [ngValue]="data">{{data.host_name}}    </option>
</select>

export class SelectOverviewExample {
     selectedDataList: any = {};
     dataLists: any[] = [
           { 'id': 1, 'host_name': 'Service 1', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user1', 'password': 'abc' },
           { 'id': 2, 'host_name': 'Service 2', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user2', 'password': 'abc' },
           { 'id': 3, 'host_name': 'Service 3', 'port': '8090', 'username': 'user3', 'password': 'abc' }
     ];

selected() {
  console.log(this.selectedDataList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution .its working fine

html

```
 <select #selecteData (change)="selected($event,selecteData.value)">
                <option>Select........</option>
                <option *ngFor="let dataList of dataLists" [value]="dataList.id">{{dataList.host_name}}</option>
            </select>
```

ts

```
selected(ev: Event, data: any) {
         for (let i = 0; i < this.dataLists.length; i++) {
            if (this.dataLists[i].id === parseInt(data, 10)) {
                console.log(this.dataLists[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        }
```